# Time delay equation

Tags: functional-equations

If $x(t)=\displaystyle\frac{1+(x(t-T))^m}{(x(t-T)))^m}$   for all $t$

where $T$ is constant

and $x(t)=x_s$ is the solution to the above equation, why can I write that:

$x_s=\displaystyle\frac{1+{x_s}^m}{{x_s}^m}$

when on the RHS $x_s$ is evaluated at a different time?

Comment: I think that $x_s$ is the constant solution. Otherwise, how could we explain the change of notation from $x$ to $x_s$?

Comment: How do we know that the solution is constant?

Comment: The equation has infinitely many solutions. One of the cases is the constant solution which satisfies $x_s=\frac{1+x_s^m}{x_s^m}$.